# How to store data retrieved from the server into an array with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me how can I store the values of the CSV file into an array that I am retrieving from the web server.

**Data example:**

```
Time2,Price,Size
0.0,20998.0,69
0.0,20999.0,18042
0.0,21001.0,14783
0.0,21003.0,100
```

Suppose I have the following scenario shown below:

```
var url1 = 'path for CSV file'
$.get(url1, function(data) {
    // data param contains all the data that I retrieved from the csv
});
```

using the above example, how can I store my data into an array so the end result looks like the following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `data` is a single string with all your csv content?  `var rows = data.split("\n")` then loop through rows and split on `,` - but that's not all a "csv" is.  You *should* also check for / parse for `"` and `""`.

Comment: I'd be surprised if nothing here can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+convert+csv+to+array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very straight forward approach:

1. Split into lines on `\n`
2. Split each line `,`

```js
const csv = `Time2,Price,Size
0.0,20998.0,69
0.0,20999.0,18042
0.0,21001.0,14783
0.0,21003.0,100`;

const result = csv.split("\n").map(l=>l.split(','));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a reducer ([`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)):

```js
// create an array of arrays
const csvLines = `Time2,Price,Size
0.0,20998.0,69
0.0,20999.0,18042
0.0,21001.0,14783
0.0,21003.0,100`
  .split("\n")
  .map(v => v.split(","));

// bonus: to array of objects
let headers = csvLines.shift();
const fromCsv = csvLines.reduce( (acc, val) => [...acc, {
      [headers[0]]: parseFloat(val[0]),
      [headers[1]]: parseFloat(val[1]),
      [headers[2]]: parseFloat(val[2]) } ], []);
      
console.log(fromCsv);
```

Comment: That isn't the result to OP requested. (although it is most appropriate :-) )